# Google embedded Map Shows only some of the places

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm using google embedded map in my website in which i want to show a places from a small town "SADALGA". However it shows only some of the places. Do i need to but API KEY to show all placess marked on map in the tows SADALGA..?

Note: Address i'm passing dynamically.. for which in db i have specila column named map_address

google embedded code:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="300" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://www.google.com/maps?q=<?php echo $map_address;?>&output=embed"></iframe>
```

Comment: if you tried anything than please update your codes here (php code, jscode)

Comment: i have shown the code above..that is what all i know about google embedded map